# In Portugal, what exactly is a Cimbalino

Tags: food-and-drink, portugal, portuguese-language

In Portugal, you normally order a short shot of coffee (espresso) asking for "um café" or "uma [bica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bica_(coffee))", which is pretty much used all over the country.

But lately I started to notice that some people order a "um cimbalino".

Can I use this word to order espresso coffee all over Portugal? And btw., where does that word "cimbalino" come from and does it really mean the same (a espresso coffee)?

Comment: I think this is on-topic here, but you might get more informed answers on [Portuguese Language Stack Exchange](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @mlc I've changed the last sentence to point out what I'd like to know in first place "can I order a cimbalino in all Portugal?) and secondarily the word's origin. Is it better now?

Comment: This [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cimbalino) page has all the answers

Comment: @NeanDerThal thanks for the link! So can I order  a cimbalino in the Algarve? would people know what it means?

Comment: @Vickel the Algarve is southern Portugal. The Wiktionary link says 'cimbalino' is derived from a trademark name and is used in the north, and 'bica' is used in the south. *I started to notice that some people order a "um cimbalino".* Where were you?